# ASP.net Page Persistence Regarding Saving State

Tags: asp.net, .net, viewstate, response.redirect

Currently, I have an asp.net web application that links to another page.  The enduser clicks on a link which response.redirects to a validation page.  This works correctly they finish with the validation page and this response.redirects them back to the initial page that they started on.  The specific problem is that when the user is brought back to the initial page any work that they had previously completed is now gone (aka filling in textboxes/dropdowns etc.).  I have been reviewing the best way of making sure this doesn't continue to occur and everything seems to be pointing to saving the view state of the page prior to redirecting to the validation page, and then reloading this view state upon coming back to the initial page.  Although, I fell like using response.redirects will not allow this to occur.  Now if the end user was just clicking the back button then this would work.  Basically, my problem is keeping the data that my enduser input present on the initial page.  Any thoughts/ideas/suggestions will be greatly appreciated.  Please go easy as it is my first post here.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure whether or not this will solve your issues but long time ago there was an idea to store the ViewState on the server and restore it on demand.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/persistentstatepage.aspx

This came at a price of turning of the validation. I remember I tweaked it a little bit:

http://netpl.blogspot.com/2007/11/persistentstatepage-with-event.html

I hope you'll find it useful.

Comment: I am no longer going this route but if I did this would be the solution.  I am going to end up rewriting how this section of code works with an ajaxpopup box for the validation screen.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest looking at this article:  [9 ways to persist user stat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300437.aspx)

Which state choice is really up to you and what your application requires.  Its a little old (2003) but a good guide to user state.

Comment: Thanks for this page I have seen this before, but reviewing it again was helpful